# Não consigo copiar um vetor de strings para um vetor de strings em uma struct

Tags: c, string, struct

Estou a horas quebrando cabeça e não consigo resolver.
Quero copiar uma string nova e coloca-la na primeira posição de um vetor de strings em uma struct. Porém, quando tento copiar o novo valor que vai ser adicionado a primeira posição simplesmente da um erro ("error: assignment to expression with array type"). Estou começando agora em programação, então desde já me perdoe pelas leiguices.

Segue o codigo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char nome[30];
    int rg;
}PESSOA;

PESSOA *alocaMemoria(int tam){
    PESSOA *v;

    v=(PESSOA*)(malloc(tam*sizeof(PESSOA)));

    return v;
}

void adicionaValor(PESSOA *vetor, int tam){
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
        printf("Nome: ");
        scanf("%s", &vetor->nome);
        printf("RG: ");
        scanf("%d", &vetor->rg);
    }
}

void mostraVetor(PESSOA *vetor, int tam){
    int i;
    PESSOA *pVetor;

    pVetor=vetor;

    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
        printf("Nome: %s\n", pVetor->nome);
        printf("RG: %d\n", pVetor->rg);
    }
}

void adicionaInicio(PESSOA *vetor, int tam, char *nome, int rg){
    PESSOA *novoVetorAux;

    novoVetorAux[0].nome=nome;
    novoVetorAux[0].rg=rg;

}

int main(){

    PESSOA *vetor;
    int tam, op, rg;
    char nome[30];

    printf("Selecione a opcao desejada: ");
    scanf("%d", &op);

    printf("1 - Inicia vetor\n");
    printf("2 - Adiciona valores as casas do vetor\n");
    printf("3 - Adiciona valores a primeira casa do vetor\n");
    printf("6 - Mostra Vetor em ordem\n");

    switch(op){
        case 1:
            printf("Tamanho do vetor: ");
            scanf("%d", &tam);

            vetor=alocaMemoria(tam);
        break;

        case 2:

            adicionaValor(&vetor, tam);
        break;

        case 3:
            printf("Nome: ");
            scanf("%s", &nome);
            printf("RG: ");
            scanf("%d", &rg);

            adicionaInicio(&vetor, tam, &nome, rg);
        break;

        case 6:
            mostraVetor(&vetor, tam);
        break;
    }



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c-strings não são "atribuíves" dessa forma. Você precisa copiar, de fato, caractere por caractere, de um array para o outro. Para isso, use a função `strcpy()` definida no cabeçalho `string.h`.

Não testei seu código, mas me parece que tem mais problemas do que somente isso... Enfim, para usar a função, faça:

```
strcpy( arrayDestino, arrayOrigem );
```